# How can i add an image in nvd3 piechart legend?

Tags: nvd3.js

I want to add an image in nvd3 piechart legend instead of text.
I have this code but it changes only the text in the tooltip with the image. I want to change and the text in the legend with the same image.

```
var testdata = [
{
  key: "<img src="+"./imgs/facebook.jpg"+">",
  y: 1
},
{
  key: ""<img src="+"./imgs/twitter.jpg"+">"",
  y: 2 
}  ];
nv.addGraph(function() { 

var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.key})
    .labelThreshold(.08)
    .showLabels(true)
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
    .donut(true);



  chart.pie.donutLabelsOutside(true).donut(true);

  d3.select("#mypiechart")
    .datum(testdata)
    .transition().duration(1200)
    .call(chart);

return chart;});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with nvd3.js.  The tooltip works because the `img` element you have specified is being set into a `div` that isn't contained within the `svg` element.  It doesn't work for the legend or chart labels because those are built using svg `text` elements.  In order to show an image within the chart `svg` we'd need to use an svg `image` element.

We could build the svg `image` elements if we hack the nvd3.js code.  Here's an outline of what you could do to get the legend working.  You could then decide if you'd want to try something similar in the `nv.models.pie` code for the chart labels or if you'd just want to set `chart.showLabels` to `false` in your chart configuration.

Add a new key in your data to provide the image path:

```
var testdata = [
{
  key: "<img src="+"./imgs/facebook.jpg"+">",
  y: 1,
  image_path: "./imgs/facebook.jpg"
},
{
  key: "<img src="+"./imgs/twitter.jpg"+">",
  y: 2,
  image_path: "./imgs/twitter.jpg"
}  ];
```

Update the `nv.models.legend` code to show the image:

```
seriesEnter.append('circle')
    .style('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('class','nv-legend-symbol')
    .attr('r', 5);
// Add an svg image into the legend
seriesEnter.append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', function(d) { return d.image_path} )
  .attr('height',20)
  .attr('width',20)
  .attr('y', '-10')
  .attr('x', '8');
```

Update the `nv.models.legend` code to not show the key:

```
// Don't add the key value into the legend text
//series.select('text').text(getKey);
```

Update the `nv.models.legend` code to consider the image width when determining the legend layout:

```
//seriesWidths.push(nodeTextLength + 28); // 28 is ~ the width of the circle plus some padding
//Include image width...
seriesWidths.push(nodeTextLength + 48);
```