# How can i add an image inside nvd3 piechart slices?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to add an icon inside nvd3 piechart slices.
I want this:

[image]

Any help?

EDIT:

The html code of the piechart is:

```
<g class="nv-pieWrap">
<g class="nvd3 nv-wrap nv-pie nv-chart-9221" transform="translate(0,0)">
<g>
<g class="nv-pie" transform="translate(270,145.5)">
<g class="nv-slice" fill="#3b5998" stroke="#3b5998"><path d="M7.127208979246237e-15,-116.4A116.4,116.4 0 0,1 115.55131294501349,-14.030469581719618L72.21957059063342,-8.769043488574761A72.75,72.75 0 0,0 4.454505612028897e-15,-72.75Z"></path></g>
<g class="nv-slice" fill="#326ada" stroke="#326ada"><path d="M115.55131294501349,-14.030469581719618A116.4,116.4 0 1,1 -1.2476559499083328e-13,-116.4L-7.79784968692708e-14,-72.75A72.75,72.75 0 1,0 72.21957059063342,-8.769043488574761Z"></path></g>

</g>
<g class="nv-pieLabels" transform="translate(270,145.5)"></g></g></g></g>
```

After reading this [How can i add an image in nvd3 piechart legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315208/how-can-i-add-an-image-in-nvd3-piechart-legend)

i added an image_path in my data and a added to the js this code

```
        var slices = wrap.select('.nv-pie').selectAll('.nv-slice')
                  .data(pie);


     var ae = slices.enter().append('g')
                  .attr('class', 'nv-slice')
                  .on('mouseover', function(d,i){
                    d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
                    dispatch.elementMouseover({
                        label: getX(d.data),
                        value: getY(d.data),
                        point: d.data,
                        pointIndex: i,
                        pos: [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY],
                        id: id
                    });
                  })
                  .on('mouseout', function(d,i){
                    d3.select(this).classed('hover', false);
                    dispatch.elementMouseout({
                        label: getX(d.data),
                        value: getY(d.data),
                        point: d.data,
                        index: i,
                        id: id
                    });
                  })
                  .on('click', function(d,i) {
                    dispatch.elementClick({
                        label: getX(d.data),
                        value: getY(d.data),
                        point: d.data,
                        index: i,
                        pos: d3.event,
                        id: id
                    });
                    d3.event.stopPropagation();
                  })
                  .on('dblclick', function(d,i) {
                    dispatch.elementDblClick({
                        label: getX(d.data),
                        value: getY(d.data),
                        point: d.data,
                        index: i,
                        pos: d3.event,
                        id: id
                    });
                    d3.event.stopPropagation();
                  });
 /////////////I ADDED THIS APPEND
         ae.append('image')
          .attr('xlink:href', function(d) { return d.image_path} )
          .attr('height',16)
          .attr('width',16)
          .attr('y', '-10')
          .attr('x', '8');
    ///////////////////////////////

 slices
            .attr('fill', function(d,i) { return color(d, i); })
            .attr('stroke', function(d,i) { return color(d, i); });

        var paths = ae.append('path')
            .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });
            //.attr('d', arc);
```

Comment: NVD3 doesn't really allow you to do that level of customisation, so for a simple thing like this it would almost certainly be easier to do it in pure D3. You would basically have to append an `image` element at the appropriate position. There are several examples for how to do this with text -- all you should need to change is the type of element and its attributes.

Comment: If you inspect the element, and post the results we can see if there is a class or ID that can let you access these elements. With those, you should be able to append an image and center it using a bounding box.

Comment: @Elijah: This approach won't work because you can't take the center of the bounding box -- e.g. for the larger slice in the image above it would be in the center of the entire chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hack the `nv.d3.js` code to allow this, it would just take a few steps.

Define the image path for each element in the data set:

```
var testdata = [
{
  key: "<img src="+"./imgs/facebook.jpg"+">",
  y: 1,
  image_path: "./imgs/facebook.jpg"
},
{
  key: "<img src="+"./imgs/twitter.jpg"+">",
  y: 2,
  image_path: "./imgs/twitter.jpg"
}];
```

Then update the `nv.models.pie` code with something like this...

Add an anchor for the image:

```
pieLabels.enter().append("g").classed("nv-label",true)

  ...

  group.append('text')
      .style('text-anchor', labelSunbeamLayout ? ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end') : 'middle') //center the text on it's origin or begin/end if orthogonal aligned
      .style('fill', '#000')

  // Set up the anchor for the image
  group.append('image')
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('y', '-10')
    .attr('x', '-10');
```

Hide the text label and show the image:

```
// Don't insert the label text.  We're using images.
// pieLabels.select(".nv-label text")
//       .style('text-anchor', labelSunbeamLayout ? ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end') : 'middle') //center the text on it's origin or begin/end if orthogonal aligned
//       .text(function(d, i) {
//         var percent = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2 * Math.PI);
//         var labelTypes = {
//           "key" : getX(d.data),
//           "value": getY(d.data),
//           "percent": d3.format('%')(percent)
//         };
//         return (d.value && percent > labelThreshold) ? labelTypes[labelType] : '';
//       });

// Show the image if the slice is large enough
pieLabels.select(".nv-label image")
  .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
    var percent = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2 * Math.PI);
    return (d.data.image_path && percent > labelThreshold) ? d.data.image_path : '';
  });
```

You may need to adjust the numbers a bit depending upon your needs.